# Screen saver dependent on files C

Tags: c, dll, sdl, screensaver

I made a screen saver in C that uses SDL. I put it in System32 along with the folder of pictures it uses and SDL.dll but I get an error when I try to run it. It can't find SDL.dll! It works in any other folder with SDL.dll in it. Why not System32? I'm not even trying to run it as a screen saver. When I right click it and hit "Test" it says it can't find SDL.dll. What is wrong? What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `SDL.dll` somewhere on the `PATH`. Windows needs to be able to find it, and it doesn't know to look in the folder you created.

You can tell how Windows looks for DLLs by reading the documentation for [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The first directory searched is the directory containing the image
>   file used to create the calling process (for more information, see the
>   CreateProcess function). Doing this allows private dynamic-link
>   library (DLL) files associated with a process to be found without
>   adding the process's installed directory to the PATH environment
>   variable. If a relative path is specified, the entire relative path is
>   appended to every token in the DLL search path list. To load a module
>   from a relative path without searching any other path, use
>   GetFullPathName to get a nonrelative path and call LoadLibrary with
>   the nonrelative path. For more information on the DLL search order,
>   see [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Ah, thanks. I guess I might need to go poking around and modifying the code for sdl_main.lib

Comment: Why would you need to modify the library? This is a Windows API issue, and changing the library source won't fix anything. You need to a) install your DLL into the Windows\System32 folder, or b) add the DLL's folder into the system `PATH`.